# Integrate Micrometer into GeoServer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, geoserver, micrometer

Micrometer can be automatically integrated into Spring Boot applications simply by using the `spring-boot-starter-actuator` and `micrometer-registry-prometheus` dependencies and then adding `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,prometheus` to `application.properties`.

Now I want to know if the same is possible with GeoServer, which is technically not a Spring *Boot* application but is build with Spring.

I have a Java Project which fetches GeoServer as dependency from maven and which I can extend (for example adding a REST Endpoint). This project is then build to a docker container from which it can be startet. In this project there are no GeoServer source files.

```
@RestController
@ControllerAdvice
@RequestMapping(path = "/actuator/prometheus")
public class MetricsEndpointController extends RestBaseController {

    PrometheusMeterRegistry prometheusRegistry = new PrometheusMeterRegistry(PrometheusConfig.DEFAULT);
    
    @GetMapping(produces = { MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE })
    public String prometheus() {
        return "";
    }

}
```

I don't know how to integrate Micrometer into the GeoServer application, so that I automatically get default metrics like one would get when included the dependencies to a spring boot application.

Comment: Please add details on what you have tried so far. You'll need to create an endpoint for Prometheus to scrape and instantiate a Prometheus meter registry.

Comment: GeoServer is written using classic Spring, mostly using XML context files (with a few modules using annotations). Can micrometer be used with classic spring?

Comment: Yes. Micrometer does not require Spring Boot. It can be used with classic Spring (or without Spring at all)

Comment: I've included more details into my question

Comment: I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55395769/micrometer-metrics-with-spring-java-no-spring-boot